# how to make delay the visible of two different images in matching cards game VB

Tags: vb.net, matching

I'd like to program the matching cards game, the first level we have 4 photo, if they are the same, the score will increase, if not it will close again.
I used `button` and `picturebox` (invisible), with `button click` the `picturebox` visible become true, so I must click two `buttons` to decide if they are matching or different, the problem in the different images case, the second photo does not appear. I try to put delay function but the same situation.

```
Dim P, Q, As Boolean
Dim X, Y, Z, W As Integer

Sub AA() 
    'if p false means no button clicked if q true two 
    'buttons clicked
    If P = False Then     
        P = True                   
    Else
        Q = True
    End If

    If Q Then
        If (X = 1 And Y = 1) Then
            PictureBox11.Visible = True
            PictureBox14.Visible = True
            Button1.Visible = False
            Button4.Visible = False
            X = 0
            Y = 0
        ElseIf (Z = 1 And W = 1) Then
            PictureBox12.Visible = True
            PictureBox13.Visible = True
            Button3.Visible = False
            Button2.Visible = False
            Z = 0
            W = 0
        Else  
            Z = 0
            Y = 0
            W = 0
            X = 0
            PictureBox11.Visible = False 
            PictureBox12.Visible = False
            PictureBox13.Visible = False
            PictureBox14.Visible = False
        End If  

        P = False
        Q = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles       Button1.Click

    PictureBox11.Visible = True
    X = 1

    Call AA()
end sub
'and the same for 4 buttons
```

Comment: You might like to check out this demo of mine to see whether it helps: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?722573-Match-Two-Game&highlight=

Comment: thaaaaaaaanxx , i love u